# Play framework - retrieving the Date header in the request

Tags: scala, http, playframework, request

I need to access the `Date:` header when I handle the request, but this seems to be "swallowed" by the framework; any other header (even made up `FooBar` ones) show up and I can get them, but this gives me `None` (I'm using Postman to send a simple GET request - everything else works just fine):

```
println("Date: " + request.headers.get("Date").getOrElse("no date!"))
```

returns `"no date!"` no matter how I try to send something sensible.

I'm wondering whether this gets processed before the `request` object reaches my Action.

I need the actual string value sent, as this should be part of the request's signature - so an equivalent `Date` object representing the same value would not be of much use (as it needs to be part of the hash, to avoid replay attacks).

Just as a test, I replaced the `Date` header with a `Date-Auth` one, and this one shows up just fine:

```
ArrayBuffer((Date-Auth, ArrayBuffer(Wed, 15 Nov 2014 06:25:24 GMT))
```

Any ideas or suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you absolutely positive there is a `Date` header in your request? Your code looks correct, I don't see any reason why Play would handle this specific header differently.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is a Date Header in your request (tested with tools like firebug or wireshark)?
Browsers do not need to send a Date header.

[RFC 2616 (HTTP 1.1)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.18) from the Date section (14.18)

> Clients SHOULD only send a Date header field in messages that include an entity-body, as in the case of the PUT and POST requests, and even then it is optional. A client without a clock MUST NOT send a Date header field in a request.

Comment: Yes - for one, I'm using Postman, and all other headers are coming across just fine; for the other, by simply replacing the `Date` with `Date-Auth` (completely made up) in the same field, gets that header across.  This is a POST request; and in any event, that normative is irrelevant in my case, as I'm the one writing the client too.

Answer (score 0):

I stand corrected - it turns out that Chrome blocks a whole bunch of headers:
http://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests

I wrote a Python Flask test server and, in fact, the `Date` header is not there.
That page has also a fix, which works just fine with Postman Version 0.10.4.3 and Interceptor([1](http://www.getpostman.com)).

sorry for wasting everyone's time!

[1](http://www.getpostman.com) Incidentally, IMO [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com) is the best REST client and has now also some awesome looks, beyond incredible functionality.  If you're working with REST APIs, I highly recommend it.